# How can I implement multi-tenancy authentication in AWS Cognito user pool?

Tags: active-directory, amazon-cognito, multi-tenant

I'm building an authentication system on AWS using Cognito, and I want to support multi-tenancy. To achieve this, I've created a Cognito User Pool for handling user registration and authentication. Additionally, I've integrated Cognito with an identity provider like Active Directory. However, I'm also exploring other ways to customize the authentication flow, especially when dealing with multiple Active Directory instances for different tenants. Can you provide guidance or alternatives for achieving this?